# isolating unique lists from 2d array that do not exist in another

Tags: python, arrays, list, 2d

Given this segment -

```
for e, m in enumerate(mfilist):
    if not any(m[0] and m[1] and m[2] and m[3] and m[4] in sublist for sublist in internaltbl):
        goodlist.append(m)
        copygood.append(copylist[e])
```

A few lists should be appending to goodlist as they do not have duplicates existing in internaltbl with the combined elements filtered above.

For example, here's one entry in mfilist:

```
[u'{8E25CEF3-4098-4148-9122-E9978DCB077D}', u'{889280F1-8F0B-48E8-A8D2-FCA44BA3D492}', u'{1A290F5B-CB24-4E5B-8342-B6B256150D1F}', 2, 'C', '', datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 14, 0, 0), '', '', '', 'FALSE', 'A1', 'Map']
```

And one from internaltbl:

```
[u'Historical', u'{03810429-88FD-4ACD-A8EE-1A6E21250B94}', u'{4FBB1469-1C0D-4DBE-9C98-CFECA12748C3}', u'{ED96E80A-A20F-4DEA-92A6-2DF783C7665F}', 2, u'C', u'PPR, u'ArcMap Document (*.mxd)', u'L', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 1, 0, 0), u'LG', u'CHJ', u'TB', None, u'Proposed']
```

I've since made sure every element is of string value to avoid 'coercion to unicode' issues or the like, but the issue persists - nothing ever appends.

There is no combination of those GUIDS, then "2, C" existing in internaltbl.

Thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

You're running into an issue with operator precedence. In this bit:

```
m[0] and m[1] and m[2] and m[3] and m[4] in sublist
```

What you want to be evaluated is this:

```
(m[0] in sublist) and (m[1] in sublist) and ...
```

But what Python sees is this:

```
m[0] and m[1] and m[2] and m[3] and (m[4] in sublist)
```

Because non-empty strings duck-type to True, the result is True so long as m[4] is in sublist and all of the other strings are non-empty.

If you don't want to write each membership test separately, this is a shortcut:

```
all(x in sublist for x in [m[1], m[2], m[3], m[4]])
```

Comment: I was referencing line 2 of your example. I missed m[0] in my example, but the principle of the solution still works. Do you understand the gist of your mistake?

Comment: Thanks for the help. The longform works, but I didn't manage to implement your shortcut correctly. I tried something to the effect of all((x in sublist for x in [m[1], m[2], m[3], m[4]]) for sublist in internaltbl). Anyway, who's the douche who downvoted us? Yours was the only answer that worked!